# Create a jrate plug in dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a table where the user can see the rating of a product and want to dynamically create jRate instances base on the number of table row.

```
var row = $("#PrctTable tr").length;
    if(row > 0 ){
        var ratingID = [];
        var ratingScore = [];
        for(i=0;i<row-1;i++){
            $(".pr-rating").find('div').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id','rating'+i);
            ratingID.push('rating'+i);

            });
                $(".rating-score").each(function(){
                    ratingScore.push(parseFloat($.trim($(this).text())));
                });
                $(ratingID[i]).jRate({
                    startColor:"#FDD835",
                    endColor:"#FDD835",
                    precision: 0.01,
                    strokeWidth: '5px',
                    readOnly: true,
                    rating:ratingScore[i]
                });
        }
    }
```

Is this correct way of doing it?

Comment: I tried to run this with the suggestion below, I only get one jrate instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
ratingID.push('rating'+i);
```

to

```
ratingID.push('.rating'+i);
```

note the `.` class selector, which I think is what you are missing in order to make it work. If it's an id instead then use `#` rather than `.`.

Comment: Thank sir, but I use the ratingID to only store the names of ID's that will be use for the individual div where jrate will be put.

Comment: yes, but that's why `$(ratingID[i]).jRate({` won't work - there's no selector in there, you could even add it there instead of to the array, e.g. `$('.' + ratingID[i]).jRate({` or `$('#' + ratingID[i]).jRate({`